# Is it safe to use include for sensitive data in PHP?

Tags: php, include

I have 10 PHP pages that all need the same encryption function along with their keys. 
Is it secure to add the PHP file with the encryption functions and keys via include in the 10 PHP files?

Example:

```
<?php
include('/files/encrypt.php')
?>
```

Comment: They've got to get in their somehow, no?

Comment: @Johnconde has a point. How would you propose to include them if you didn't go down that route?

Comment: @ScottMcGready I would not use include but hardcode them in every single PHP page. By looking at the upvotes, it seems that not even that is really secure.

Comment: I really hope you don't do that in a production environment. Or anywhere for that matter.

Comment: What would you possibly imagine is a security flaw of using `include` vs. hardcoding the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really hope there's absolutely no way to access the keys through a URL. You should put these outside your public web root.

If the keys are inside the web root, you will probably be exposed. A simple mistake could reveal your PHP source and then it's game over.

Comment: The keys are inside the PHP file which is in a subfolder, not the root. `If the keys are inside the web root, you will probably be exposed. A simple mistake could reveal your PHP source and then it's game over.` What mistake could reveal my PHP source and why is the web root different from a web sub folder? `e.g. http://www.example.com/files/encrypt.php`

Comment: The most obvious mistake is accidentally disabling the interpreting of PHP files. If your web server doesn't know how to handle them it will often just dump their raw contents out as plain text. That's **super bad**. In the past several tiny flaws in Apache `httpd` have made it possible to trick the server into emitting the raw source, something that's scary enough without leaking your private keys.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What is a safe way to store or include passwords, keys, tokens and such sensitive stuff then?

Comment: Just be absolutely certain the files are located outside of the web root. In practice this means you have a `public/` folder inside of which you have PHP scripts that are accessed by the public, and something else, like `include/` that's at the same level as `public/` that has your "other" more sensitive stuff in it. Most web frameworks come with some sort of convention here. To test, try turning off your PHP module and see if you can fetch any of the sensitive files by specifying their path in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to store them above the web root and pull them in with require_once().

Comment: You need to store them *outside* the web root to be secure.

Comment: @musa It's a bit ambiguous. Could mean "at", which is how I read it at first.

Comment: depending on the framework (zend etc), storing them in /library or in your config file could be relatively safe, otherwise, store them "outside" of your web root.